# How to get LCOM(Lack of Cohesion of Methods) metric in SonarQube 4.2?

Tags: java, sonarqube, lcom

Is *LCOM* metric available with *SonarQube 4.2* version ?

I need this metric to be added in my report, but i don't see its available.

Please let me know is there any specific jar to be added to get this metric. This metric was available in Sonar 3.7

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no plugin for this, so if you want it, you'll have to develop it.

In any case, we've deprecated and removed this metric because we found it was difficult to compute it correctly and therefore to use it correctly. Maybe this could give you a hint on whether you should keep on considering it or not...

Answer (score 3):

Since Sonar 4.1 LCOM4 metric has been removed because of too many false positives. See [Remove support of LCOM4](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4853).